# Marklogic 8.0.4 running without license key

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I am running Marklogic version 8.0.4 without license key. Just want to know the validity time for this unlicensed version and it is only for testing purpose. Since I had a developer license which is used in another machine.

Answer (score 3):

From the [MarkLogic documentation](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/installation/procedures#id_18057)

> MarkLogic will run without a license key, but you should enter a valid
>   key for what you are licensed for after installing MarkLogic. At any
>   time, you can change the license key for a host from the Host Status
>   page. You might need to change the license key if your license key
>   expires, if you need to use some features that are not covered in your
>   existing license key, if you upgrade your hardware with more CPUs
>   and/or more cores, if you need a license that covers a larger
>   database, if you require different languages, or for various other
>   reasons. Changing the license key sometimes results in an automatic
>   restart of MarkLogic (for example, if your new license enables a new
>   language).

You can also get another free developers license by joining the [MarkLogic developers community](https://developer.marklogic.com/free-developer) if you need access to some of the licensed features.